# Praw script throws an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw

```
import praw
import time

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent = "A bot by /u/")

r.login()
print("Logging in...")

cache = []

def run_bot():
    print("Grabbing subreddit...")
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit("test").get_new(limit=1)
    print("The subreddit selected was /r/Test")
    subreddit.add_comment('Cat.')

while True:
    run_bot()
    time.sleep(10)
```

I'm trying to make a bot that comments on new submissions with the phrase *Cat.*, but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\bot.py", line 19, in <module>
    run_bot()
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\bot.py", line 15, in run_bot
    subreddit.add_comment('Cat.')
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'add_comment'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. How about tell us why you think it doesn't work (is there an error?), and if you have isolated the problem to anything specific?

Comment: @Andrew  Here is the [error.](http://pastebin.com/KAdEu29J) This is a pastebin link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subredit
```

is a generator. That means you have to iterate over its results. By using a for loop you can access its results like this:

```
for x in subreddit:
    x.add_comment('Cat.')
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Code-only answers are not very helpful to readers (unless they contain inline comments, which is not the case here).

Comment: I love you. Worked like a charm. I don't understand what it means though.

Comment: Think of a generator as a nebulous glob of results. It needs to be iterated over (it's an iterator) to access them. It's like calling a function directly without running the function -- it returns "function object at xxa63294xz" or whatever. (A generator is a function too)